# Unlink Uploaded file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

I already made a script for uploading files using angularjs. The files were successfully uploaded to the folder, but my problem is, when removing one file from the queue, it does not delete the file from the folder, does anyone know how to unlink or remove the file when i click on the remove folder, i'm using angular to upload files. thanks

Answer (score 0):

call a php script (by angular $http) and unlink the file.

```
//php
unlink(PATH_TO_FILE);
```